# Ajax response in a div having images blinks the images for a second, can we avoid this?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, chat

I have a div, it's actually a chat panel in html. I update it with Ajax. It has thumbnails of the chat users. And whenever the response loads, it blinks all the images for a second. Is there some way to retain the loaded images in cashe. It looks very odd when the response loads after every four seconds and the thumbnails of users blink.
I am attaching the image to explain my point.
[image]

Comment: Can you attach your ajax code? You are probably replacing whole HTML of the div, instead of just appending new lines to the end of the div, and that causes the flicker.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening because the messages are being dynamically refreshed. Even the image tag is being replaced, with the very same code. To change this, perhaps you should contain the body of the message in a span like `<span class="txtbody"> ... </span>` where you can then update the txtbody, rather than the entire post template and avatar.  You'd have to do a each loop and update that way on a interval. Or you can provide the class name with a token from the ID of the message to update it dynamically that way without a interval. Something like `<span class="txtb-23"> ... </span>` where "23" is the ID of the comment.

So instead you just need to draw the message and update the message, rather then the entire thing. You shouldn't be refreshing all the elements, it's a waste of resources. You should only push a new message, if there is a new message.

Also by only pushing new messages, and updating the bodies of old messages, you can do those neat little jquery slider effects by loading the new comment into a container with `display:none;` and then using something like `.slideDown()` :)

Pre-caching the image may also help in this instance. I'm not entirely sure how it's called so that's no guarantee. CSS, or JavaScript can be used to pre-load a image. See: http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be easily avoid by replacing the images with elements having a background image.

```
@media screen {
element.className
{
background: transparent url('') 0px 0px
}
}
```

Also you might want to look into [Better Image Caching with CSS](http://perishablepress.com/css-image-caching/)